# $N$ - Dimensional Solid of Revolution.

Tags: geometry

Ok, so if you take a line, or a group of lines, and rotate them $360$ degrees along their axis, you'll get a $3$-dimensional solid.

Is it possible to take a $3$-dimensional figure and rotate it along it's own axis to yield a higher dimensional geometry?

Could you, for example, generate an $N$-dimensional geometry through this process?

Answer (score 0):

If I take a line and rotate it around its axis, I still get a line.  If I take a disk and rotate it around a line through the center, I get a ball.  Yes, in $R^4$ you can rotate a ball around a line through its center and get a four dimensional ball.  If you start with a unit radius ball centered at the origin and rotate around the $x$ axis into the direction of $w$, the fourth coordinate, each point of the sphere describes a circle at a constant $x$ coordinate.  The point $(x_0,y_0,z_0,0)$ traces out a circle.  Two of the equations are  $x=x_0, y^2+z^2+w^2=y_0^2+z_0^2$ but I can't figure out the third.  You need three to make a 1D shape in 4D.